# computer freezes

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, freeze

Sometimes my computer freezes while using Ubuntu. But it works fine when I use Windows 10. I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 with dual booting Windows 10.

My system specs are:

- 2.41GHz Intel Pentium inside processor with
- 4 GB RAM

I want to know the cause of the problem.
Does the operating system not support my hardware or did something wrong happened during the installation/software update?

And how can I fix it?

Comment: Your specs are enough to run ubuntu 18.04 and you shouldn't be facing this, unless your drivers don't communicate with the OS. It can be fixed, however. did you install the 64 bit version? What is your graphics driver? can you update your questions to show these details? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)